Sort by version numbers
I have a column (called versnum in this example) with version numbers. If I sort them with order by versnum I get for example:
2.4.11
2.4.12
2.4.5
2.4.6

I want to sort them like strverscmp() does it in C. So I want the order
2.4.5
2.4.6
2.4.11
2.4.12

Is there a way to do this with with standard sql operators or functions?
In case it is not possible, my idea is to create a function that expands each part of the version number to e.g. 4 digits. So I can use order by myfunction(versnum). Maybe anyone of you have already implemented something like this and like to share it.
2      => 0002
2.4    => 0002.0004
2.4.5  => 0002.0004.0005
2.4.11 => 0002.0004.0011

Summary of answers and comments
Store version numbers normalized
When storing a version in a normalized format, sorting becomes easy, but the original format is lost. One solution can be, to store the version number twice, original for display and normalized for ordering. However, this goes against the rule of avoiding redundant data.
Alternatively I can use spaces (or control characters like CTRL-A)  for padding. And on display the spaces will be removed.
My solution for a SQL function (see my answer)
This solution is guaranteed to be slower than the previous one. An index is not helpful here because of the function call. For a precise analysis, you would have to compare the times with the other methods.
mysql sorting of version numbers
The solutions mentioned in mysql sorting of version numbers look very well. I especially like the REGEXP solution. I plan some time analyses.

Storing the data normalized, would make the things very easy

@nbk Maybe, but it distorts the actual version number. The column reflects a version number of a tool (self-disclosure), in the example by Apache. And for normalization I need a function, the same function that I can use for ordering.

No it would not diszord 0005 would only exist ones and the bridge table would make insert delete and update very easy. Mariadb has still no split function, but you need to split the column up pad left the result and then concat them again, a costly endeavour

Will you be sorting by this data frequently? (i.e. is this for OLTP, or for occasional reports/queries (OLAP)?) - I"m asking because there are performance implications which dictate the best solution - I agree with nbk in that you might want to consider normalizing the representation somehow (not necessarily to 4 separate columns - you could instead use a normalized bigint representation that allows for efficient sorting but requires bitshifting on INSERT/UPDATE.

@Dai I think if go with normalization, then two columns can work. The two float type columns.  The first column with major and minor version and second column contain release version.

I don't recommend using float types in a database: they cannot relably store exact values - that's why they're called "approximate types" in many systems/languages - and it will break = comparisons.

@Dai Yes, you are correct. Can't use float. Thank you.

If the app is written in PHP, I think it has a "natural" sort order for exactly what you are doing.

@RickJames The database should order this, because of paging. With a PHP solution, the complete table must be loaded and sorted to find out the elements to display.

@Wiimm - File a feature request at bugs.mysql.com and/or mariadb.com

Its already there - natural_sort_key -  SELECT c FROM t1 ORDER BY NATURAL_SORT_KEY(versnum);

You can use Substring Index to split the string into the 3 parts:
SELECT 
  Product.Version
  FROM Product ORDER BY
    cast(substring_index(version, '.', 1) as int), /* Major Version */
    cast(substring_index(substring_index(version, '.', 2), '.', -1) as int), /* Minor Version */
    cast(substring_index(version, '.', -1) as int); /* Release Version */

Playground Link
This method only works for versions consisting of exactly 3 parts and requires some duplication each if you want to add support for a 4th part, so there might also be a better way. Tuple support in SQL seems very limited though.

I have implemented an sql function as solution of my question. In the question I will discuss comments and answers.
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS x_version %%
CREATE FUNCTION x_version( vers MEDIUMTEXT, fw int )
        # param:
        #   vers : versions number, format: a[.b]*[ extra]
        #   fw   : field width of version parts
        RETURNS VARCHAR(100) DETERMINISTIC NO SQL
BEGIN
        DECLARE result TEXT DEFAULT '';
        DECLARE extra TEXT DEFAULT '';
        DECLARE pos INT;

        # extract optional extra info after first space
        SET pos = POSITION( ' ' in vers );
        IF pos > 0 THEN
            SET extra = SUBSTRING(vers,pos);
            SET vers = TRIM(SUBSTRING(vers,1,pos-1));
        END IF;

        iterator:
        LOOP
            IF CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(vers)) = 0 OR vers IS NULL THEN
                LEAVE iterator;
            END IF;
            SET pos = POSITION( '.' in vers );
            IF pos = 0 THEN
                SET pos = LENGTH(vers)+1;
            END IF;
            SET result = CONCAT(result,'.',lpad(TRIM(SUBSTRING(vers,1,pos-1)),fw,'0'));
            SET vers = SUBSTRING(vers,pos+1);
        END LOOP;
        return CONCAT(SUBSTRING(result,2),extra);
END;
%%


I think in the question last comment there is a good link. it solves the problem very well.

@Developer See my Summary in the question.
